# Running from AWS Lambda function: can see CloudWatch logs, except in axios's continuation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Running the code below in AWS Lambda, I can see in CloudWatch the first part (`Sending out to: ${url}`), but not the part in `axios`'s `.then`:

```
console.log(`Sending out to: ${url}`);

axios.post(url, 'Hi from Lambda!')
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Axios succeeded:", response);
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Axios failed:", error);
    });
```

Am I missing something? why isn't the response/error visible in CloudWatch?

(I know that `axios` is working because when I'm using an incorrect address in `url`, I'm getting e.g. an `ECONNREFUSED` error)

#### Edit - full code:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (event, connection, publish) => {
    console.log(`The event:`, event);
    console.log(`Connection:`, connection);

    var domainName = event.requestContext.domainName;
    var stage = event.requestContext.stage;
    var connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;

    var url = `https://${domainName}/${stage}/@connections/${connectionId}`;

    console.log(`Sending out to: ${url}`);

    axios.post(url, 'Hi from Lambda!')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log("Axios succeeded:", response);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("Axios failed:", error);
        });

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: Show the function this code is running in, e.g. is it async, how is it called, etc

Comment: @404 - included the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function finished right after Axios request is called. This means the function does not wait until the request complete.

You write the lambda as an `async` function, then just use `await` to wait for the Axios request.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => { // event and context
  console.log(`The event:`, event);
  console.log(`Connection:`, context);

  var domainName = event.requestContext.domainName;
  var stage = event.requestContext.stage;
  var connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;

  var url = `https://${domainName}/${stage}/@connections/${connectionId}`;

  console.log(`Sending out to: ${url}`);

  const response = await axios.post(url, 'Hi from Lambda!') // wait until request response
    .catch(error => { // If you don't care about the error, just print it out an continue
      console.log("Axios failed:", error);
    });

  console.log("Axios succeeded:", response);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
};
```